# Should Islam.SE hold any contest/competition?

Tags: discussion

There should be a contest held based upon Islam, such as "Islamic Art Competition".

Our fellow site "Arqade" is have(ing) it's [Screenshot of the Week #78](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/screenshot-of-the-week-78-three-years-of-screenshot-of-the-week-celebration/16609#16609)

(*Where you have to submit a screenshot as a answer, the most upvoted answer wins.*)

Thought we could do something similar related to Islam, it would be fun and engaging.

However I know Islam.SE and other sites are not similar and our community is not the most engaging, it would be nice if we had any contest related to Islam.

Also were there any previously held contest here?

Answer (score 1):

If you take out Arqade's "Screenshot" aspect, the basic idea of having a regular themed competition would still probably work here. Maybe monthly rather than weekly, due to the lower activity levels on this site.

The basic idea is, the community would suggest themes or topics (this could probably be done on meta and/or discussed in a dedicated chat room) and one is picked each month. People could be encouraged to write new posts that are related to that topic, either posting new interesting questions, or posting new answers to old unanswered questions.

Posts which qualify would be tracked and at the end of the month the community would basically choose which one they liked the best; maybe separate categories for best question vs best answer, that sorta thing.

We could probably do something similar with Islamic art etc, but at this point I'm not sure we have enough artists (experienced or amateur) to make such a competition viable. That's definitely something I'd love to see though.